# Get relative path from $().css("background-image")

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

In the CSS I have `background-image: url(folder/bg.jpg);`.

For this, JQuery's `css("background-image")` returns `url(http://www.example.com/folder/bg.jpg)`,

but I need `folder/bg.jpg` only.

I'm looking for a regex that would solve this for me.

Comment: Why would you need css computed style to return relative path?

Comment: +1 @A. Wolf. Adding to that if you want to reuse the background image for some other element, definitely you can do that with the absolute path.

Comment: It should be an input parameter for a function that calculates the dominant color of an image. When the page loads, divs that have a background image, receive a background color based on their background image.

Comment: @tom i still dont understand what is wrong with absolute path

Comment: I just prefer a relative path as it is simpler. But you're right, it should also work with an absolute one. In this case I only need to get rid of `url(` and `)` that can be done simply using e.g. `.substring()` and `.length`. I was just wondering if it was possible to get the relative path, but if it turns out to be too complicated I'll of course not prefer the relative one over the absolute just because I like it better.

Comment: @tom thecomputed style property is browser dependant, you shouldnt rely on it. If im correct some browser would return the relative, other the absolute. So you would have better to find an other way than using a css property. You should read about XY problem

Comment: _"thecomputed style property is browser dependant, you shouldnt rely on it. If im correct some browser would return the relative, other the absolute."_ I didn't know that. I thought it's reliable. Then the best thing to do after knowing this I think is to use a `data-*` attribute in my HTML, store the URL there, and read that one using JavaScript.

Comment: @tom ya, imho that's the best thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/\//`, `Array.prototype.join()` , `String.prototype.slice()`

```js
$("div").html(
  
  $("div").css("backgroundImage").split(/\//)
  .slice(-2).join("/").slice(0, -1)

)
```

```css
div {
  background-image: url(http://www.example.com/folder/bg.jpg)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Of course the paths are always different, this one was only an example.

Comment: You surely have better to replace window.location.hostname in returned string but still wouldnt be the path as set in css property

Comment: Thank you guest271314, it does exactly what I needed, so I accept it as an answer to my question, but thanks to @A. Wolff now I know that what I want to accomplish is not the best way to solve my problem, so I won't read the background-image CSS property, I think I'd better use a data-* attribute in HTML. Still, this answer might be helpful for someone looking for some similar string manipulation methods to process an URL.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the best regex to all cases, but you get the point.

```
/* Explaining:
/ regex here /
[^\/]+  ---> will match anything before a / (https:)
\/\/    ---> the // after https: 
[^\/]+  ---> will match anything before / (www.example.com)
\/      ---> will match /
(.*)    ---> the rest of url (that you want)
So, you need to get the [1] index of the returned array.
*/ 
"http://www.example.com/folder/bg.jpg".match(/[^\/]+\/\/[^\/]+\/(.*)/)[1]
```

Will return: "folder/bg.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery will return the absolute path, you will never be able to determine the relative path without string manipulation knowing what to remove given how nested your page may be in your directory hierarchy.  I would recommend string replace with Regex.  See plnkr below.

```
    $("div").click(function() {
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(http://run.plnkr.co/cybkjF7HN9sYH3oS/','').replace(')','');
        alert(bg);
    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zkeoRE?p=preview